# Questio about AdMob ad url to application

Tags: android, admob

I wonder something on AdMob, google recently changed Android Market to Play Store. The url to the application on AdMob ad is like "market://details?id=com.myapp". When I added the link to my application on Play Store to the ad, it changed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp to market://details?id=com.myapp

What I want to ask is, does it really successfully redirect to my app? Because I started a compaign for testing, with 1000 clicks, I have about 40 downloads, and I doubt they are even from admob... what do you think about, is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link will redirect to Google Play, but will work with older non-updated versions of Android Market.

You should use referral tracking to see if your campaign is useful.  See:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide?hl=es-ES

Comment: This page https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2414071?hl=en states that "No action is necessary to configure download tracking for Android". So it sounds like referral tracking is now automatic and it is no longer necessary to follow that portion of the guide. Anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that although the AdMob UI says the link is market, it does indeed hit the play store.